# Python CRON google flexible app engine not working

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cron, app-engine-flexible

I have the following `cron.yaml`:

```
cron:
- description: "TEST_TEST_TEST"
- url: /cronBatchClean
- schedule: every 2 minutes
```

And then in `app.yaml`:

```
service: environ-flexible
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

With this as `main.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/cronBatchClean')
def cronBatchClean():
   print("CRON_CHECK", file=sys.stderr)
   return "CRON_CHECK"
```

When I type in the full URL, I receive "CRON_CHECK" on screen but this doesn't seem to be executing. Also in App Engine dashboard, when I click on CRON jobs there aren't any listed.

Any help in getting this to execute would be much appreciated,

Thanks :)

**EDIT 1**

I now have the cron task executing but I'm receiving a `404` error. When I type the full URL (that is - https://.appspot.com/cronBatchClean) the respective code executes.

I added a `GET` handler but I'm still not receiving any luck.

```
@app.route('/cronBatchClean', methods=['GET'])
def cronBatchClean():

   print("CRON_JOB_PRINT", file=sys.stderr)

   return "CRON_CHECK"
```

Comment: have you deployed your `cron.yaml`

Comment: @skaul05 yes i have

Comment: Check your `default` service logs - do you see the `/cronBatchClean` requests going there?

Comment: When I call the url it works but there's no CRON tasks executing @DanCornilescu

Answer (score 3):

In the `cron.yaml` there are unnecessary “-” characters, that are starting the new list. [YAML Syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/YAMLSyntax.html)

Correct format for Cron Jobs `cron.yaml`, [see Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref):

```
cron: 
- description: "TEST_TEST_TEST" 
  url: /cronBatchClean 
  schedule: every 2 minutes
```

To deploy Cron Job use [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron#upload-cron) :

```
$ gcloud app deploy cron.yaml
```

---

Comment: Still no luck. There's no CRON jobs listed under app engine.

Comment: If the cron job is not listed then it wasn't deployed correctly. How did you deploy it?

Answer (score 0):

**To solve this problem i changed the service name to default then i deploy with the default service the cron job task path was pointed to the default path of app engine so that when the task was scheduled 404 error raised because the path doesn't match when the service name set to "environ-flexible"**

> In app.yaml

change :

```
service: environ-flexible
```

to

```
service: default
```